# Azure Communication Service Redirect Call not Working

Tags: azure-communication-services

I seem to always be getting a "line busy" when using redirectCall. Can someone help me figure out if I'm doing something wrong? I was able to answer the call just fine and reject it, but redirecting is not working.

I've tried:

- Changing the sourceCallIdNumber to the ACS number instead of the incoming call number
- Using a different target phone number
- Looking for any options in redirectCall that would fix the issue

Here's Microsoft's documentation I'm referring to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/how-tos/call-automation/actions-for-call-control?tabs=javascript#redirect-a-call

```
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';
import { CallAutomationClient } from '@azure/communication-call-automation';

class SubscriptionValidationEventData {
  validationUrl: string;
  validationCode: string;
}

//const callbackUri = "redacted";
const client = new CallAutomationClient(process.env.COMMUNICATION_SERVICES_CONNECTION_STRING as string);


export default async function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
  if (req.headers['aeg-event-type'] === 'SubscriptionValidation') {
    try {
      const eventData: SubscriptionValidationEventData = req.body[0].data;

      console.log(`Got SubscriptionValidation event data, validationCode: ${eventData.validationCode}, validationUrl: ${eventData.validationUrl}`);
      
      const responseData = {
        validationResponse: eventData.validationCode,
      };

      return res.status(200).json(responseData);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error handling SubscriptionValidation event:', error);
      return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal server error.' });
    }
  }
  
  if (req.body[0].eventType && req.body[0].eventType === 'Microsoft.Communication.IncomingCall') {
    const incomingCallContext = req.body[0].data.incomingCallContext;
    console.log('Heres the incoming number', req.body[0].data.from.phoneNumber.value)
    console.log('Heres the incoming call context', incomingCallContext)

    const callerIdNumber = { phoneNumber: req.body[0].data.from.phoneNumber.value };
      const target = {
          targetParticipant: { phoneNumber: "+1xxxxxxxxxx" }, 
          sourceCallIdNumber: callerIdNumber,
      };
    await client.redirectCall(incomingCallContext, target);
    res.status(200).json([]);
    

  }

  return res.status(404).json({ error: 'Not found.' });
}
```

I'm expecting it to ring another number, but it's getting "Line busy" every time.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! I had Receive calls enabled, but not Make calls in the phone number in ACS.